# OpenCV: black image captured from usb camera

Tags: opencv, camera, usb

I am trying to capture an image frame from a USB camera using opencv. However I am always getting a black frame. I have read many posts with this issue and tried all the suggestions but nothing worked for me.

I started using the code discussed here:
http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Using-USB-Camera-td6786148.html

I have tried including the method cvWaitKey(1000) after many 'critical' sentences. As you can see the waiting value is very high (1000).

I have also tried to save the image frame and, equally, it is a black image.

I am using the following system:

- OpenCV 2.2.0
- Windows 7, 32 bits
- Visual Studio 2010 (C++)
- a board usb camera (which I do not know the manufacturer)

The usb camera works well with AMCAP.EXE 1.00.

Could it be because of the camera drivers being used by Windows? Could I change to other drivers that work better for OpenCV 2.2.0?

Thanks

Comment: Can i see your code tat grabs the frame part? So that I can help. Cheers (:

Comment: Or wat do your output window says?

Comment: I tried with a Logitech cam and it all works well... so I guess it is not a code problem... I am still thinking that the drivers play a key role in this...

Comment: Cuz I also did snap a black image with my usb camera before, but mangaed to solve it. You are right when you said driver play a role. This is actually if and only if the camera is not compatible with OpenCV. But I have yet to come across such webcam. Some other method could be to use a format that the USB driver is using, (declare it and set the height and width). The codes, are you using "CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);" and "IplImage* img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture);" ?

Comment: @rockinfresh, can you write some code to exemplify your suggestion about the use of a format that the USB driver is using?

Comment: sure, give me some time if you don't mind, I am super busy this days. Will try find time by today or tomorrow to post a standard answer of what I mean. (:

Answer (score 6):

Ok. As I promised to your request in the comments, and sorry to keep you waiting, really been busy. Barely had time to post this answer too. But here it is:

This is me simulating that opencv is capturing black image. On the output window, which I had asked you in the comments about what it says, shows that there is an error.

[image]

After investigating, I realised that it is due to the camera's available format:
[image]

Of cuz, this is a lousier camera. If you have a better camera like the logitech one, you can see that the format available is so much more. 
[image]

There are lots of methods, you can try some thing like

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 640); 
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 480); 
capture.set (CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('B', 'G', 'R', '3'));//diff from mine, using as example
```

then the webcam will be able to snap. This webcam is bit faulty, hence the image snapped is not that beautiful.[image]

Hope this is your problem. but it may not be the case too. I like debugging problems, but I can't put down all the possible causes that this happen for you as I am really busy, as you asked for an example, this is one of them. Cheers. If you could tell me what you output window error says, I probably can help more.

> EDIT(to answer more in your comments):

Ok, I want you to try a few things:

1)First, instead of using `cvQueryFrame`, or similar capturing methods, I want you to try use that webcam to capture a video instead. Wait up to maybe say 10 secs to see if it's successful. Reason being, some cameras(lower quality ones) take quite a while to warm up and the first few frames they capture may be an empty one.

2) If the step one doesn't work, try typing

```
cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;
```

and paste the results for media I/O and Video I/O? I want to see the results. I would suspect your library dependencies too, but since you said it works with a logitech camera, I doubt that's the case. Of course, there's always a chance it's due to that the camera is not compatible to OpenCV. Does the camera have any brands by the way?

3) Alternatively, just search for usb drivers online and install it, I had a friend who did this for a similar problem, but not sure the process of that.

Comment: Hope it helps, and if it works, do accept my answer(I noticed you don't like to accept people answer to your questions, can I ask why?). If it is useful or helpful, do consider upvoting it.

Comment: can you please share some code of your detectDevices.exe program? I wanted to do something like this before and as far as I read in other threads, openCV can not create a list of available devices... by the way, I just discovered the "acepted answer" option very recently, with this problem in hand, and I have been unable to solve it, yet.... If I manage to solve this, I will have no problem to tick the corresponding accepted answer.

Comment: my output window gives no error. Everything works well and the only thing is that the image I get is black.

Comment: Haha, I meant the other questions you have actually and people answered the question. But looks like you learnt how to use it(: Ok. I edited my answer. Hope it helps, my gut feeling is that it's step one, where the camera take a while to warm up. Step 3 should work too, but I never done it tat way before. Do let me know how it goes(:

Comment: The detectDevices.exe program was actually found online 1 or 2 years back. I had tried finding it for you, but I am afraid, the search was futile. Sorry.

Comment: Suggestion 1) gives allways the black window. After a while working (in the order of tens of seconds) it opens a new black window. This proccess is repeated until I finish the application. Suggestion 2) gives the following syntax errror: the identifier "getBuildInformation" is not defined. Note that I did not build openCV from source using cmake. Instead, I used an EXE installer to be used with VS2010.

Comment: oh... Then it could be because of that, otherwise my other suspicion is it may not be compatible with opencv. What brand is it? You have other cameras that can work right? If not, try installing a new usb driver for the one that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing, I would suggest is, visit this link and check your camera is working or not

http://www.youronlinemirror.com/

if yes, then go through below link to get started with things, you ll also find a good opencv c++ code out there, the code which you are using is of opencv1 api's c code, I would rather encourage you to go for c++ than the old version of opencv.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html

if you want an answer for your code, then, its simple, as you are saying its giving a black screen, which happened in my case when i started things out with opencv, 
it isnt able to take the data from device, so, try this, it might work, as it did for me.

add

```
cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

before

```
IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

Comment: My camera works at youronlinemirror.com. I also tried the C++ interface with the code at: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#VideoCapture I also tried your code suggestion. I always get the black image.

Comment: oh, I am out of answers then, try using the latest version of opencv, it might solve the prob.
Most of the cases, it does solve the issue which is rare in our case.

But, when you say you are getting a black image, is the window getting closed after a second or its there with black screen as a normal output window.

Comment: the window closes when the program finishes

Comment: when the program finishes ?
you meant, its getting closed when you stop debugging or , its getting closed automatically in few seconds after the start.

Comment: okay, then, try out with latest version of opencv, it might give results.

Comment: I doubt its the OpenCV Version. I am using 2.2 myself with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem as yours. Then I just changed the version from 3.1.0 to 2.4.13, then my webcam works! No more black images. I guess the 3 version is not compatible with the vs15. Thinking you may have already solved the problem long ago. But just post to let others know if they happen to have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same black screen problem while running OpenCV-related programs. So instead of using USB cam I used mobile camera which worked perfectly fine. Use Google apps such as DroidCam (install DroidCam on mobile as well as on laptop/PC) to connect your mobile camera to laptop through Wi-Fi.