# Why are webcam images taken with Python so dark?

Tags: python, opencv

I've showed in various ways how to take images with a webcam in Python (see [How can I take camera images with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28418962/562769)). You can see that the images taken with Python are considerably darker than images taken with JavaScript. What is wrong?

### Image example

The image on the left was taken with http://martin-thoma.com/html5/webcam/, the one on the right with the following Python code. Both were taken with the same (controlled) lightning situation (it was dark outside and I only had some electrical lights on) and the same webcam.

[image]

### Code example

```
import cv2
camera_port = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv2.imwrite("opencv.png", image)
del(camera)  # so that others can use the camera as soon as possible
```

### Question

Why is the image taken with Python image considerably darker than the one taken with JavaScript and how do I fix it?

(Getting a similar image quality; simply making it brighter will probably not fix it.)

Note to the "how do I fix it": It does not need to be opencv. If you know a possibility to take webcam images with Python [with another package](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18134/python-library-for-taking-camera-images?noredirect=1#comment39770_18134) (or without a package) that is also ok.

Comment: I guess `camera.read()` has some arguments to control the camera settings. Did you check that out? (`help(camera.read)`)

Comment: @septi: it doesn't. See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read

Comment: Sanity check: `return_value` is `True`, right?

Comment: It says: "The methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call." So you should have a look at `grab()` and `retrieve()`. `camera.read()` is only a wrapper which obviously takes the default settings for those two functions.

Comment: Looks related: [Why does OpenCV give me a black screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/720379)

Comment: There are several parameters such as exposure time and so on to get pictures from camera. See if those parameters are the same between the two platforms.

Comment: @septi: I did look that over and there are no additional parameters.

Comment: Also looking relevant: [OpenCV: black image captured from usb camera](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21849300)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you have to wait for the camera to be ready.

This code works for me:

```
from SimpleCV import Camera
import time
cam = Camera()
time.sleep(3)
img = cam.getImage()
img.save("simplecv.png")
```

I took the idea from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106770/take-a-picture-from-terminal#answer-276232) and this is the most convincing explanation I found:

> The first few frames are dark on some devices because it's the first
>   frame after initializing the camera and it may be required to pull a
>   few frames so that the camera has time to adjust brightness
>   automatically.
>   [reference](https://github.com/Moonware/cordova-cameraserver/issues/3#issuecomment-148493737)

So IMHO in order to be sure about the quality of the image, regardless of the programming language, at the startup of a camera device is necessary to wait a few seconds and/or discard a few frames before taking an image.

Answer (score 11):

Faced the same problem. I tried this and it works.

```
import cv2
camera_port = 0 
ramp_frames = 30 
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
def get_image():
 retval, im = camera.read()
 return im 
for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
 temp = camera.read()

camera_capture = get_image()
filename = "image.jpg"
cv2.imwrite(filename,camera_capture)
del(camera)
```

I think it's about adjusting the camera to light.

The former image:
[image: former image]

The later image:

[image: later image]

Answer (score 2):

Tidying up Keerthana's answer results in my code looking like this

```
import cv2
import time

def main():
    capture = capture_write()


def capture_write(filename="image.jpeg", port=0, ramp_frames=30, x=1280, y=720):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(port)

    # Set Resolution
    camera.set(3, x)
    camera.set(4, y)

    # Adjust camera lighting
    for i in range(ramp_frames):
        temp = camera.read()
    retval, im = camera.read()
    cv2.imwrite(filename,im)
    del(camera)
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why you use range instead of xrange it could work for Python 3 as well

Comment: good idea! The code has been modified to work in Python 2 and 3 ^_^