# OpenCV, webcam capture result in black screen

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, capture

I have tried several proposals about this problem. 
Unfortunately i was not able to get it working.

I have tried opencv 2.4.13.3 and even 3.3.0 but it does not make any difference.

Here is my code:

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
{
    cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
    return -1;
}

double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

namedWindow("MyVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

while (1)
{
    Mat frame;

    cap.retrieve(frame);

    int i = 0;                                   //index, we use it for testing

    while ((i++ < 100) && !cap.read(frame)) //skip unread frames
    {
        cout << "frame " << i << " skipped" << endl;
    }

    if (i >= 100)                                //check webcam_0 failure
    {
        cout << "cannot read frames from webcam_0, check drivers" << endl;
        waitKey(0);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "cam is ready" << endl;
    }

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
        break;
    }

    imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

    if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
    {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

It always skipps frames (as it should until it was able to get a correct frame). But after 100 skipped frames, it still get no frames.

The Webcam works fine with the camera app from Win10. So the camera itself is not the problem.

System: Win10 x64.
Tried with x86 and x64 version of opencv

I hope you can help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849300/opencv-black-image-captured-from-usb-camera) might help

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this with no success. Still black screen.